# Javascript toFixed localized?

Tags: javascript, localization

Do you know if `toFixed` is a localized function?

I mean, will this:

```
var n = 100.67287;
alert(n.toFixed(2));
```

show "**100.67**" on English US OS/browsers
and "**100,67**" (with comma) on Italian OS/browsers?
(Italian or any other local system that uses comma as decimal separator).

Comment: Take a look at [`Number.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Number/ToLocaleString).

Comment: For anyone looking for a React Native solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56243866/152711

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No, this will always return a point. The [ECMA 262-spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf) [15.7.4.5] states it should be a point.

Comment: This link is broken and there are "too many pending edits", so here's an updated link: https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-262/

Answer (score 48):

Late addition: with `Number.toLocaleString()` now available on everything bar IE 10 & below, this works, albeit rather long-winded:

```js
var n = 100.67287;
console.log(n.toLocaleString(undefined, {
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  maximumFractionDigits: 2
}));
```

Using *undefined* or 'default' for the language code will use the browser default language to format the number.

See [developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) for full details.

If you're free to extend the Number prototype, you could defined `Number.toLocaleFixed()`.

Comment: Long-winded as it may be, it's the best solution I've seen so far.

Comment: Or simply n.toFixed(2).toLocaleString()

Comment: @dataman That’s different: `Number.prototype.toLocaleString` will format the decimal point according to the locale, e.g. `"100,67287"` instead of `"100.67287"`. `toFixed` circumvents this and always uses a `.`. Your suggestion would use `String.prototype.toLocaleString`, and it is no longer aware of the numeric properties of `n`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
var n = 100.67287;
alert(parseFloat(n.toFixed(2)).toLocaleString());
```

On my german system the result is

```
100,67
```

Comment: This is a clever hack, but won't work correctly for 100.00, which will result in "100" via toLocaleString()

Comment: For display purposes - skip the parseFloat and leave as a string.

Answer (score -2):

No sadly, there is no real solution in pure jQuery/JavaScript. You'll need Globalize. The problem is that both toFixed() and toLocaleString() take a number and return a string. So you can never use them together. :( If you call foo.toFixed(2).toLocaleString() you won't get the localization (i.e. '1.234' in en should be '1,234' in fr) because its working on the result of toFixed() which is a string, not a number. :(

Comment: Support for the ECMA-402 Internationalization API has been specified since ECMAScript 2015 (ed. 6), so this answer is no longer current as *Number.prototype.toLocaleString* can specify both language specific formatting and number of decimal places per [ChrisV's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39686116/257182).