# How can I parse user input decimals based on the current locale in React Native, using a dot or comma for the decimal separator?

Tags: react-native, localization

I have a number input that pops up a "numeric" text input in React Native.

In many locales this brings up a numeric pad with a comma for decimal separation, instead of a dot.  This results in inputs like "100,1" instead of "100.1".

JavaScript's `Number(value)` only works with dot decimals, not commas.  How can I determine the user's current format in order to properly parse the input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function will **parse** a decimal input based on the current locale, [using react-native-localize](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-localize#getnumberformatsettings):

```js
import { getNumberFormatSettings } from "react-native-localize";

export function parseLocaleNumber(stringNumber: string) {
  const { decimalSeparator, groupingSeparator } = getNumberFormatSettings();

  return Number(
    stringNumber
      .replace(new RegExp(`\\${groupingSeparator}`, "g"), "")
      .replace(new RegExp(`\\${decimalSeparator}`), "."),
  );
}
```

For good measure, this complementary function provides **toFixed** functionality based on locale:

```js
export function toFixedLocale(value: number, numDigits: number) {
  const standardFixedString = value.toFixed(numDigits);

  const { decimalSeparator } = getNumberFormatSettings();

  if (decimalSeparator === ",") {
    return standardFixedString.replace(".", ",");
  } else {
    return standardFixedString; // Locale matches JavaScript default
  }
}
```

(parseLocaleNumber based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/42213804/152711)

Comment: you don't really need regex for this - `replace(groupingSeparator, '')` and `replace(decimalSeparator, '.')` should be fine